# Rendering D3 Collapsible tree view inside a Bootbox popup?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bootbox

I have a D3 collapsible tree view of a distribution, and I have a working code for it. I want to add it to a webpage, where the view should be visible as a popup on click of a button. I have been trying to use bootbox for creating the popup box. However, I am unable to understand how can I do this. I have tried `bootbox.prompt` and `bootbox.dialog` and passed my D3 tree code, but that doesn't work.
Can you suggest any other way to do it.

I have a working understanding of D3, and little to none knowledge of JS. Thanks!

Comment: "that doesn't work" - it would be helpful to see what you're trying to do - can't really troubleshoot without _some_ sort of example of what you tried. Most likely, though, you need to move your D3 init code into the `shown.bs.modal` event, triggered once the dialog has been shown to the user.

Comment: Sure, I'll add some examples. thanks for the feedback @TiesonT.